# Here api - I am using here map licence key ,App Id and App key Premium user but warning message show invalidate license key

Tags: here-api

Here api - I am using here map licence key ,App Id and App key Premium user but warning message show invalidate license key

We are trying to download offline map but license key invalidate in iOS Application.

Comment: Can you explain in more details? Code snippets and error messages would help. Also what is the API version you use? 3.0 or 3.1?

Comment: We are trying to download map in online and want to load map in offline that time we are using license key,app id and App key.when we call download map api its return invalid license key.Can you suggest how can we use offline map

Comment: I think it should work fine if you use version 3.0. Just generate new APP ID & APP CODE in https://developer.here.com/projects.
If you use version 3.1, then you need to use API KEY instead.

If you still have issues after steps I provided above, then please provide some code snippets, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in our Authentication and Authorization Developer Guide:

> When creating your application (identified by its APP ID), you will
> also choose the type of credentials to use for authentication. HERE
> provides either OAuth 2.0 Token or API Key credentials for better
> security. App Code Credentials will no longer be provided for new
> projects.
>
> The supported authentication credential types are:
>
> - List item
> - API Key Credentials OAuth 2.0
> - Token Credentials APP CODE Credentials

Please use the latest authentication method which is API Key Credentials.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/index.html